# I tried to make a class that had the basic functions of a calculator ut it gave an error

Tags: python, function, class

```
1. I have created a class to have the basic functions of a calculator and the class is named Calculator

    class Calculator:
        def __init__(self, num1, num2):
            self.num1 = num1
            self.num2 = num2
    
        def addition(self, num1, num2):
            finalNum = num1 + num2
            print(finalNum)
    
        def extraction(self, num1, num2):
            finalNum = num1 - num2
            return finalNum
    
        def multiplication(self, num1, num2):
            finalNum = num1 * num2
            return finalNum
    
        def division(self, num1, num2):
            finalNum = num1 / num2
            return finalNum
    
    
    calc = Calculator()
    calc2 = Calculator()
    calc3 = Calculator()
    calc4 = Calculator()
    
    print(calc.addition(14,76))
```

2.I have created 4 variables to have this class inside them
but when I try to print out the function it gives an error.
It says TypeError: **init**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'num1' and 'num2'

Comment: The way your class is defined, you need to provide two numbers when creating an instance. It doesn't make much sense to do it given that all the methods require inputs anyway. So I'd just leave `def __init__(self): pass`. Or even get rid of `init` altogether...

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the **init** function is constructor，so you have to declare the variable like:
calc = Calculator(74, 23)

or you can change the **init** function like

```
def __init__(self, num1=0, num2=0):
    self.num1 = num1
    self.num2 = num2
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not given the parameters that are required, how about leaving the init empty(because you won't need it) and just getting parameters for your functions?

Do this instead:

```
class Calculator:
        def __init__(self):
            pass
    
        def addition(self, num1, num2):
            finalNum = num1 + num2
            return finalNum
    
        def extraction(self, num1, num2):
            finalNum = num1 - num2
            return finalNum
    
        def multiplication(self, num1, num2):
            finalNum = num1 * num2
            return finalNum
    
        def division(self, num1, num2):
            finalNum = num1 / num2
            return finalNum
    
    
calc = Calculator()
calc2 = Calculator()
calc3 = Calculator()
calc4 = Calculator()
    
print(calc.addition(14,76))
```

Hope it works, iyi gunler :)

Comment: Would appreciate it if you verify the answer when you're done :)

Comment: Thank you for the help it worked. Teşekkür ederim